# Breadth-First Search with obstacles

Tags: javafx, breadth-first-search, path-finding

I'm currently making a game as a school project and I'm trying to figure out the pathfinding of enemies. I've made a basic BFS which works pretty well but does not take in account obstacles, so enemies are stuck by an obstacle is there's one when trying to reach the player. I've tried different things but all I got was null pointer (which I kind of understand, but I don't know how to make this works).

```
public class BFS {
    
    private Player player;
    private Field field;
    private Queue<Tile> queue;
    private HashMap<Tile, Tile> parents;
    private ArrayList<Tile> adjTiles;
    
    public BFS(Player player, Field field) {
        this.player = player;
        this.field = field;
        this.queue = new LinkedList<>();
        this.parents = new HashMap<Tile, Tile>();
        this.adjTiles = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public void lancerBFS() {
        int x = player.getIndiceX();
        int y = player.getIndiceY();
        Tile player = field.getNextTile(y, x);
        
        this.parents.clear();
        this.queue.clear();
        this.adjTiles.clear();
    
        this.queue.add(field.getNextTile(y, x));
        this.parents.put(field.getNextTile(y, x), field.getNextTile(y, x));
        
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Tile temp = queue.remove();
            y = temp.getI();
            x = temp.getJ();
            
            if (x > 0) {
                this.adjTiles.add(field.getNextTile(y, x-1));
            }
            if (y > 0) {
                this.adjTiles.add(field.getNextTile(y-1, x));
            }
            if (x < 24) {
                this.adjTiles.add(field.getNextTile(y, x+1));
            }
            if (y < 24) {
                this.adjTiles.add(field.getNextTile(y+1, x));
            }
            
            for (int i = 0 ; i < adjTiles.size() ; i++) {
                
                if (!this.parents.containsKey(adjTiles.get(i))) {
                    this.parents.put(this.adjTiles.get(i), temp);
                    this.queue.add(this.adjTiles.get(i));
                }               
            }
            
            this.adjTiles.clear();
        }       
    }
    
    public Tile searchWay(AnimatedEntity entity) {
        int x = entity.getIndiceX();
        int y = entity.getIndiceY();
        
        Tile t = this.field.getNextTile(y, x);
        
        return this.parents.get(t);
    }
    
    public HashMap<Tile, Tile> getParents() {
        return parents;
    }   
}
```

How I use it (my tiles are 32x32 on a 25x25 map, and enemies move 4 pixels by 4 pixels)

```
public void moveEnemy(AnimatedEntity e) {
    Tile nextTile = this.bfs.searchWay(e);
    Tile enemyAt = this.map.getNextTile(e.getIndiceY(), e.getIndiceX());
    
    if (nextTile.getI() == enemyAt.getI() && nextTile.getJ() < enemyAt.getJ()) {
        e.moveLeft(entities, inanimatedEntities);
    }
    if (nextTile.getI() < enemyAt.getI() && nextTile.getJ() == enemyAt.getJ()) {
        e.moveUp(entities, inanimatedEntities);
    }
    if (nextTile.getI() == enemyAt.getI() && nextTile.getJ() > enemyAt.getJ()) {
        e.moveRight(entities, inanimatedEntities);
    }
    if (nextTile.getI() > enemyAt.getI() && nextTile.getJ() == enemyAt.getJ()) {
        e.moveDown(entities, inanimatedEntities);
    }   
}
```

How enemies get stuck in game:

[image]

How enemies get stuck after trying to include isObstacle notion

[image]

Comment: can you provide a sample use-case, what exactly the problem?

Comment: All you need to do is check, if the tile is an obstacle in your inner loop. `for (Tile t : adjTiles) { if (!t.isBlocked() && this.parents.putIfAbsent(t, temp) == null) { this.queue.add(t);}}`

Comment: So I added a screenshot of ingame and the code for the enemy movement
Thanks for the answers, I tried what you said just now Fabian but it didn't worked, gave me null pointer exceptions, and I don't really understand why because what you say makes sense, and enemies are just stuck in the middle of nowhere (I'll put a screenshot)
edit : added the screenshot in main post

Comment: As you see this post does not get much attention.Why is that ? Because se can't debug code that we don't see. For better and efficient help you'll need to post [mcve].